# How to query data in a time range from grafana with clickhouse as datasource?

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I am trying to get data of "last 5 minutes" which is an option in the above top-down menu in `grafana`. I have used the `$timeFilter` variable but when selecting the last 5 minutes, it is returning data of more than 5 minutes and the query being created is `timestamp>=(unix time)`, whereas I want the query to be "between start time and end time".

How do I achieve this in Grafana?

[image: img_timestamp]

Answer (score 0):

did you try to turn off the "extrapolate" checkbox inside Query Editor?
which clickhouse-grafana plugin version do you use?
when you use "last 5 min" query

what is your browser time zone UTC?
or you just change UTC only in "date-range" picker on top-right corner?
if yes, try to return date time range picker timezone to your timezone and try again